# Amount of money sent to the smart contract in Wei, gwei or eth?

Tags: solidity, remix

The amount of money sent to the smart contract in Wei, gwei or eth ?

So If I want to calculate the percentage of payment money and take 1% from it, and the user sent 1ETH to the smart contract will receive this money 1 eth or in Wei or in Gwei?

Depending on my debugging on remix will convert always to gwei, Is that right ?

Answer (score 2):

When you send an amount of ether or gwei or finney, the amount in smart contract will be show in wei.

**Wei** is the smallest denomination of ether (10^18).

In your case, 1% will be give back to user in wei.

In Remix IDE the conversion, for example when you send 1 gwei, will be convert automatically in wei unit.
In fact the documentation says:

> ```
> <address>.balance (uint256)
> balance of the Address in Wei
> ```

More information [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related).